# No module named 'aeneas.executetask'

Tags: google-colaboratory

!git clone https://github.com/readbeyond/aeneas.git

!git clone https://github.com/castorini/honk.git

!apt install libasound2-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 ffmpeg

cd /content/honk/

### !python keyword_data_generator.py -k "give" -s 4

and then i got an error named " No module named 'aeneas.executetask' "
how can i solve this problem?